# How do you re-set index on a dynamically added row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched and couldn't find what i'm looking for. I have a table where i'm dynamically adding rows based on an index. So i click on a link in row 5, i want to add a row at index 6. the problem lies in where when i add the rows, all the original indexes remain. All the code i've seen has to deal with names of a class or an attribute, but this is the index that is given by the html. How do i reset it? Here's my code:

```
<table class="table" id="inventoryList">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">#</th>
    <th>Class Date</th>
    <th class="text-center">Time</th>
    <th>Instruction</th>
    <th class="text-center">Registrants</th>
    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">1</td>
    <td class="">Friday, December 15, 2017</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="34" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="34" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="34" class="form-control">
        <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="34"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">2</td>
    <td class="">Thursday, December 14, 2017</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="35" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="35" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="35" class="form-control">
        <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="35"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">3</td>
    <td class="">Saturday, December 9, 2017</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="33" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="33" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="33" class="form-control">
        <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="33"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">4</td>
    <td class="">Friday, December 8, 2017</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="32" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="32" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="32" class="form-control">
        <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="32"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the jQuery part:

```
$(document).on('click','.registrants',function(){
  var curIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  $('#inventoryList tr').eq(curIndex).after('<tr><td></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: why not just use `$(this).closest('tr').after` , then you wouldn't need to find the index

Comment: dude! I'm telling you, i tried that before and it didn't work. Gave it another shot and BAM! works great. thanks!

Comment: how do i do something after the after inserted the row? after('blah',function(){});?

Comment: not sure if this would work but you could make the row you're inserting into a var - `var insert = $('<tr><td></td></tr>'); $(this).closest('tr').after(insert); insert.after('blah');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/39828/)**.

You could insert the new element directly after the clicked parent tr like :

```
$(document).on('click', '.registrants', function() {
  var curIndex = $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td></td></tr>');
})
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.registrants', function() {
  var curIndex = $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td colspan="6">NEW LINE</td></tr>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="inventoryList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Class Date</th>
      <th class="text-center">Time</th>
      <th>Instruction</th>
      <th class="text-center">Registrants</th>
      <th class="text-center">Status</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">1</td>
      <td class="">Friday, December 15, 2017</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="34" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="34" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="34" class="form-control">
          <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
          <option value="closed">Closed</option>
          <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="34"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">2</td>
      <td class="">Thursday, December 14, 2017</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="35" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="35" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="35" class="form-control">
          <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
          <option value="closed">Closed</option>
          <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="35"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">3</td>
      <td class="">Saturday, December 9, 2017</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="33" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="33" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="33" class="form-control">
          <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
          <option value="closed">Closed</option>
          <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="33"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">4</td>
      <td class="">Friday, December 8, 2017</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-time" name="course-time" data-id="32" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">...</option>

          <option value="1">1 AM</option>

          <option value="2">2 AM</option>

          <option value="3">3 AM</option>

          <option value="4">4 AM</option>

          <option value="5">5 AM</option>

          <option value="6">6 AM</option>

          <option value="7">7 AM</option>

          <option value="8" selected="">8 AM</option>

          <option value="9">9 AM</option>

          <option value="10">10 AM</option>

          <option value="11">11 AM</option>

          <option value="12">12 AM</option>

          <option value="13">1 PM</option>

          <option value="14">2 PM</option>

          <option value="15">3 PM</option>

          <option value="16">4 PM</option>

          <option value="17">5 PM</option>

          <option value="18">6 PM</option>

          <option value="19">7 PM</option>

          <option value="20">8 PM</option>

          <option value="21">9 PM</option>

          <option value="22">10 PM</option>

          <option value="23">11 PM</option>

          <option value="24">12 PM</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="">
        <select id="course-instructor" name="course-instructor" data-id="32" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Choose Instructor</option>

          <option value="1">Raymond Bieselin</option>

          <option value="2">Joseph Saglimbene</option>

          <option value="3">Raymond Scotto</option>

          <option value="4">James Lawrence</option>

          <option value="5">Richard Allen</option>

          <option value="6">Tom Flynn</option>

          <option value="7">Bob Loveridge</option>

          <option value="8">Damien Avilies</option>

          <option value="9">Paul Walsh</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="registrants" data-total="0"><i class="fa fa-user text-info" aria-hidden="true"> [0]</i></a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select id="course-status" name="course-status" data-id="32" class="form-control">
          <option value="open" selected="">Open</option>
          <option value="closed">Closed</option>
          <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="inventory-delete" data-cid="1" data-id="32"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how do i run a function after the row is inserted? I want to slideDown the newly created row, but i need to make sure it's done after it's created

Comment: Please what you mean by slideDown? else just add the code after the `after` statement .

Comment: well... what i'm really going to do is populate the just added row with ajax content so i need to makes sure that my ajax loads into that row properly

Comment: Ok, add your ajax request to the OP so we could see if there's any callback there that you could use.